# how can django view access url pattern?

Tags: django

In my urls.py, I direct traffic like this:

```
url(r'^basic/', 'mysite.views.basicHandler', name='basic'),
```

Which is handled in my views.py like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response as dr2r

def basicHandler( request ):
    rc = RequestContext(request, {
        "cdn_url" : settings.CDN_BASE_URL,
        "cdn_home" : settings.CDN_SITE_PATH
    })
    return dr2r( 'basic.html', {}, context_instance=rc )
```

My question is, how can my views handler (`basicHandler`) access the url pattern (`r'^basic/'`)?  Is that inside of the request object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can get it from the [`request.META` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META).

```
referer = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
```

Alternatively, you can resolve the URL using [`reverse()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls)

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

url = reverse('basic')
```

Comment: reverse worked (returned /basic/), but the HTTP_REFERER did not (returned None) ... any ideas what might cause that?

Comment: HTTP_REFERER, if present in the request at all, would be the URL of the previous page, not the current page. `request.path` and `request.path_info` are where I'd start. `request.resolver_match` might also be useful, depending on exactly what you want to do.